# Is there any way to set replication factor for data block invidually? I am using a single node hadoop cluster on windows 10

Tags: windows, hadoop, replication-factor

Lets Say i have 1 large file. Hdfs splits that file in 5 blocks. I want to change replication factor for block 1. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replicate a file more than the running number of datanodes. Blocks also cannot be replicated individually.